# Android Studio FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

After downgrade android studio from electric eel to giraffe, I can't build project. Android Studio throw exception `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Cactus\gradle-7.0.2\caches\jars-8\c5da5d03b7169cae3d2e5669b85ad090\android.jar.
> PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Cactus\gradle-7.0.2\caches\jars-8\c5da5d03b7169cae3d2e5669b85ad090\android.jar.
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.instrument(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$TransformFile.lambda$schedule$0(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:274)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:266)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:683)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.lambda$visitEntries$1(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visitJarContents(ClasspathWalker.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visit(ClasspathWalker.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.visitEntries(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.lambda$instrument$0(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:139)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.buildJar(ClasspathBuilder.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:53)
    ... 7 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

I was tried clean all cache, choose different JDK, but I got this error.

Comment: Try running out android studio with run as administrator

Comment: Similarly, no effect

Answer (score 2):

The problem I encountered is similar to yours, and I suspect it may be a compatibility issue between `Gradle plugin version` and `Gradle version`.

I changed it to: `Gradle plugin version` and `Gradle version` `7.3.0`, `7.4`

Then everything worked like before...

You'll find the Gradle Settings `File > Project Structure...`

[Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=en)

Comment: I can't edit Gradel plugin version because it production project.

Answer (score 1):

I encount this error(`PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9`) after upgrade AGP from 7.2.2 to 8.1.0 and Gradle 7.3.3 to 8.0.

In my scenario, I have a local plugin which is defined in other project and reference by `includeBuild` api. The plugin just implement the `AsmClassVisitorFactory` interface and create a `ClassVisitor`.

To solve the problem, you must check:

1. the AGP and asm version in the plugin project's dependency.
2. you `ClassVisitor` class must set the `api` constructor parameter to `Opcodes.ASM9`.

For example:

```kotlin
// build-logic/convention/build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    val agpVersion = "8.1.0"
    val kotlinVersion = "1.8.20"
    val asmVersion = "9.5"
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agpVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
    implementation("org.ow2.asm:asm:$asmVersion")
    implementation("org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:$asmVersion")
    implementation("org.ow2.asm:asm-util:$asmVersion")
}

// file: build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/me/lijiahui/gradle/plugin/log/LogTransform.kt
abstract class LogTransform : AsmClassVisitorFactory<InstrumentationParameters.None> {
    override fun createClassVisitor(
        classContext: ClassContext,
        nextClassVisitor: ClassVisitor
    ): ClassVisitor {
        val className = classContext.currentClassData.className
        log("createClassVisitor: $className")
        return LogClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM9, nextClassVisitor) // <== Here
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I recently removed java8 compatibility and migrated to using jdk toolchain 17. since then, a custom gradle plugin is throwing PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9 errors on kotlin sealed classes.

upgraded osm to 9.6, did not resolve the issue. only I realised it was pointing to Opcodes.ASM7 after reading your post.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JDK 17, kotlin 1.8.22 and Gradle 8.1.1 and Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.2, and below works. We have to add kapt block inside android block in your module level build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    ... your config.
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    ... your config.
}

android {
    kapt {
        javacOptions {
            option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
            option("-Xlint:deprecation", true)
            option("-Xlint:unchecked", true)
        }
        arguments {
            arg("plugin", "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:kotlin-allopen")
            arg("plugin", "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:kotlin-noarg")
        }
        useBuildCache = true
    }

    ... your config.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When encountering the error message "PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9" within a Java project in IntelliJ, it's often not immediately clear what the underlying issue is. However, based on my experience, this problem can frequently be attributed to an issue with IntelliJ's caching mechanism rather than a direct problem with your code or project configuration.

To resolve this error, I recommend performing a full restart of IntelliJ IDEA. This simple action can force the IDE to clear its internal caches and reinitialize the environment, which in many cases, rectifies the problem without the need for further troubleshooting steps.

Same cache error might happen in other IDEs as well.